# Using objects.get or objects.filter to obtain specific groups to use in form filter

Tags: python, django

I have created a form that due to segregation requirements needs me to prevent certain users from seeing certain results.

The form works perfectly, but I want to apply a filter that looks at the group of a `user` and filters the form contents based on the group the user belongs to.

views.py that renders the form with the filter.

```
def Overtime_Results(request):
employeeGroup = request.user.groups.get(name='Client1' or 'Client2' or 'Client3' or 'Client4')
overtime_data = Overtime.objects.filter(client=employeeGroup)
location = None
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OvertimeForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        location = form.data['location']
        overtimeid = Location.objects.all()
        overtime_data = Overtime.objects.filter(location=location, client=employeeGroup)
else:
    form = OvertimeForm()

template_name = "overtime/Overtime_Results.html"
context = {
    'form': form,
    'location': location, 
    'overtime_data': overtime_data,
}
return render(request, template_name, context)
```

This is the filter that checks whether the user belongs to a certain group.

```
employeeGroup = request.user.groups.get(name='Client1' or 'Client2' or 'Client3' or 'Client4')
```

I essentially want this to return whichever group the user belongs to, which will subsequently apply this to the forms filter later.

I've tried both filter, get with multiple methods. The above works, but only for Client1. Client2 and subsequentl clients don't work.

Edit: I think I need to use the equivalent to an 'in' statement in SQL. But, I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

The error I'm receiving right now is:

```
    Group matching query does not exist.
```

When accessing the page with a user that has a valid group assigned that matches the query results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this [QuerySet API Field Lookups using "in"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#in).

```
 request.user.groups.get(name__in=['Client1' ,'Client2' , 'Client3' , 'Client4'])
```

Comment: This is exactly the context I was trying to find and I just couldn't find it. This  works the way I needed it to perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your query boils down to:

```
request.user.groups.get(name='Client1')
```

This is because the result of:

```
'Client1' or 'Client2' or 'Client3' or 'Client4'
```

Will always be `'Client1'`.

If you just want to get all the groups the current user belongs to:

```
user_groups = request.user.group_set.all()
```

If your user can only belong to one group, then use:

```
user_group = request.user.group
```

Comment: This would be completely valid, except that the users belong to a couple of groups, so this returns multiple results and raises (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'). But the objective is to only obtain the group that represents the client the user is working for.

Comment: If you want to know what if the user belong's to the client's group - first get the group for the client; and then find out if the client's group is in the list of groups for this user. You need to start at the client.

Comment: This is the part I'm struggling with doing though, if the client group is just another generic group. How do I differentiate groups in a query? The only discernible difference between the groups is the name of them.

Comment: Update the question with your models.

Comment: Model for what? I'm using the default django user models for grouping. I haven't created my own user model for this project.

Comment: What is the Overtime model?

Comment: Its just a model/form that represents the information I'm rendering using the view. People are submitting Overtime information and I'm querying the table to display results. The 'client' choice in the Overtime model is the same as the user group, but they don't have any relationship at this point.

Comment: The default user in django can belong to more than one group; so you need to find all the groups that a user can belong to and then figure out the rest - beyond this I cannot help you because the details are not sufficient in your question. To find out all the groups, use `request.user.group_set.all()` - then do whatever your business logic requires.

Comment: I'm aware they can belong to more then one group, what I am asking is, if they belong to multiple groups, once I have retrieved all the groups, is there a way of saying: Does one of these groups = Client1, Client2, Client3, Client4. if they do, then update the employeeGroup variable to this group as a string.